# I just append a number to one list in a list, but why do all lists in the list' change?

Tags: python

```
In [33]: x=[[]]*6

In [34]: x

Out[34]: [[], [], [], [], [], []]

In [35]: x[0]

Out[35]: []

In [36]: x[0].append(1)

In [37]: x

Out[37]: [[1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1]]
```

I just append 1 to x[0], but why do all lists in the list x change?

Comment: I think pass by reference is something you should read about

Comment: `x=[[]]*6` creates a list with *6 references to the same empty list*.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because `x` is a list of references to the same inner list.

To create a list of 6 *different* empty lists, you can use list comprehension:

```
a = [[] for _ in range(6)]
```

Comment: I see, thank you very much

Comment: @user9412567 no problem. see update for how to achieve what you wanted